# Multiple tableview in a view controller

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I have 2 table views in a view controller. One table view displays the list of ingredients and the other displays a list of directions.

I need TableView1 to display the list without truncating the list. Right now it only shows two items and the rest are being hidden by the Label "Directions".

I want the tableview to push the label down to display all the items in the list. How do I display all the tableview data at once without scrolling the table view?

The second Table View follows the same story. It shows a list of recipe directions. Right now it will only display 3-4 items. Basically correlating to the size i have in the storyboard. I basically want the size to be dynamic.

The problem is with the UI.
Here's what I have tried.

1. Scroll Enabled = False
2. Clip subviews = False
3. Autoresize subviews = False

Additionally, here is my code to populate the list in the tableview

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Method call");
    if (tableView == self.ingredientsTableView) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Ingredients Cell";
        UITableViewCell *ingredientCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (!ingredientCell) {
            ingredientCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        //display the ingredient
        ingredientCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.recipe.ingredients[ indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Ingredient %@", ingredientCell.textLabel.text);

        //return ingredient
        return ingredientCell;

    } else if (tableView == self.directionsTableView) {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Directions Cell";
        UITableViewCell *directionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (!directionCell) {
            directionCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }

        //display the direction
        directionCell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", self.recipe.directions[ indexPath.row]];
        NSLog(@"Directions %@", directionCell.textLabel.text);

        //return ingredient
        return directionCell;

    }

    return  nil;
}
```

Comment: What did you do? Please post your code

Comment: can you post an image so we can undersatnd how are you placing your tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display all your data at once without having table to scroll, then why you are using `UITableView` ? Looking at your question, it seems like, you are displaying only `NSString` s in your table view. I would suggest you to drop `UITableView` idea and choose `UILabel` to display.

Even if your app demands `UITableView` you have to give `contentSize` / height of `UITableView` while its getting loaded depending upon the number of items in your array which is responsible for populating `UITableView`.

For eg. contentSize/height of table view = (Number of itmes in your array) * (height of your row);